# Python: How to draw a graphic with multiples lines?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a data frame with three columns. I need to draw a graph with multiple lines. In that graphic, each line represents one *id* and the x-axis represents the *month* column and the y-axis represent the *qtd* column.

```
+-----+-----+----+
|month| id  |qtd |
+-----+-----+----+
| 1   |  1  | 1  |
| 1   |  2  | 3  |
| 1   |  3  | 6  |
| 2   |  4  | 2  |
| 2   |  5  | 3  |
| 3   |  6  | 4  |
| 3   |  7  | 5  |
| 3   |  8  | 4  |
+-----+-----+----+
```

DataFrame code:

```
l=[(1,1,1),(1,2,3),(1,3,6),(2,4,2),(2,5,3),(3,6,4),(3,7,5),(3,8,4)]
names=["month","id","qtd"]
db=sqlContext.createDataFrame(l,names)
db.show()
```

Desire result:

```
plot with x=qtd, y=month and one line for each id line
```

In that example I have 3 different *id* lines, so the graphic will be plotted with three lines, but in the real data frame, the number of *id*s would be unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Pandas dataframe you can just group by `id` and plot each line like so:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for key, grp in df.groupby('id'):
    ax = grp.plot(ax=ax, x='qtd', y='month', label=key)

fig.show()
```

[image]